# Will Elijah return before the final judgement?

Tags: prophecy, elijah

I just read this passage and had never heard of this prophecy regarding Elijah.

[Malachi 4:5-6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Malachi%204&version=ESV) ESV

> “Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the great and
>   awesome day of the Lord comes. And he will turn the hearts of fathers
>   to their children and the hearts of children to their fathers, lest I
>   come and strike the land with a decree of utter destruction.”

- Taking account of this passage in Malachi, will Elijah make a re-appearance on earth at some point in the future, specifically, as it appears from the passage, at the time of or around the time of the final judgement?
- Was this a fulfilled prediction of the [transfiguration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfiguration_of_Jesus) prior to Jesus's execution?
- Was this prophecy fulfilled at some other point in the past?
- Is Malachi literally talking about Elijah coming back to earth or was he speaking metaphorically?
- How is this prophecy regarded or interpreted in dispensationalism (if at all). How so in Catholicism, or any of the other major Christian groups?
- Also, Does this passage inform the beliefs of the people at the time of Christ, when they were confused about his identity.

[Mark 6:14-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206:14-29&version=NIV) NIV

> King Herod heard about this, for Jesus’ name had become well known.
>   Some were saying, “John the Baptist has been raised from the dead, and
>   that is why miraculous powers are at work in him.”
>
> Others said, “He is Elijah.”

[Mark 8:27-28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%208&version=NIV) NIV

> Jesus and his disciples went on to the villages around Caesarea
>   Philippi. On the way he asked them, “Who do people say I am?”
>
> They replied, “Some say John the Baptist; others say Elijah; and still
>   others, one of the prophets.”

Comment: The Orthodox church believes that he will come back before the end and will be killed by the anti-Christ (Elijah hasn't died yet, remember). However, I am not sure what other churches believe. Are you looking for a universal belief or from a certain point of view?

Comment: @Bizantine Oh I would love to know orthodox, especially since I don't think there is really a universal point of view on this one.

Answer (score 7):

In Matthew 11:13-14 Jesus says John the Baptist is "the Elijah who was to come" before the Messiah.

Answer (score 5):

According to some religions Malachi is speaking literally about Elijah coming to the Earth.

Some Jewish sects believe that Elijah would come before the Second Coming and Wikipedia states that:

```
In the Talmudic literature, Elijah would visit rabbis to help solve particularly
difficult legal problems. Malachi had cited Elijah as the harbinger of the eschaton.
Thus, when confronted with reconciling impossibly conflicting laws or rituals, the 
rabbis would set aside any decision “until Elijah comes.”
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah#Elijah.27s_cup

The references you used in Mark do support this Jewish belief.

In Latter-day Saint/Mormon theology, Elijah has already come. In section 110 of The Doctrine and Covenants, which the LDS Church accepts as scripture, Elijah appeared to Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery in the Kirtland, Ohio temple on April 3, 1836.
 http://prophetjosephsmith.org/files/2008/08/elijah-kirtland-temple-mormon.jpg

Doctrine and Covenants 110:13-16 :

```
13 After this vision had closed, another great and glorious vision burst upon us; 
for Elijah the prophet, who was taken to heaven without tasting death, stood before 
us, and said:
14 Behold, the time has fully come, which was spoken of by the mouth of Malachi
—testifying that he [Elijah] should be sent, before the great and dreadful day of 
the Lord come—
15 To turn the hearts of the fathers to the children, and the children to the
fathers, lest the whole earth be smitten with a curse—
16 Therefore, the keys of this dispensation are committed into your hands; and by 
this ye may know that the great and dreadful day of the Lord is near, even at the doors.
```

They believe this appearance restored the same sealing keys that Christ referenced when speaking to Peter:

Matthew 16:19 :

```
19 And I will give unto thee the keys of the kingdom of heaven: and whatsoever thou
shalt bind on earth shall be bound in heaven: and whatsoever thou shalt loose on 
earth shall be loosed in heaven.
```

These same keys are the reason that the LDS Church builds temples and focuses so much on genealogy/family history. They believe that through the sealing keys brought by Elijah they can be with their families forever.

As far as the transfiguration is concerned in Matthew 17, that is not a "coming", just as in Acts 9 when Christ appears to Paul. This is not considered the Second Coming by Christianity.

Hope that helps.

(all references from the King James Version)

Comment: Hey @Byuiwritter, thanks for the response! Question though, how does the LDS church view Matthew 17, where Jesus says "But I tell you, Elijah has already come, and they did not recognize him" if Elijah appeared at a later time to J. Smith?

Comment: They were referring to John the Baptist at this point. "Elias" is used as a title at this point, meaning forerunner, because John the Baptist was sent to prepare the way for Jesus Christ. It also means restorer, as in someone who hasa specific mission to fulfill.  http://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/elias?lang=eng

Answer (score 4):

It's really very simple. John was not Elijah by name or body, but the flesh profits nothing; he had the spirit of Elijah. Thus, literally he was and was not Elijah. Malachi 4 is speaking of John the Baptist only in the biblical phenomenon sense of dual prophetic fulfillment. The context of the chapter is actually about the time just before the great and terrible Day of the Lord, when the faithful are joyful and the persecutors are "ashes" under their feet. In conclusion, there are two advents of Elijah to prepare the way for two advents of Messiah. We know this is true because the hearts of Jews have not been turned back to the messianic faiths of their fathers. If they studied prophecy of Scripture half as much as the mysticism of Kaballa or rabbinical interpretations in Mishnah, they would not need Elijah. Yet they teach in Judaism that Elijah must come and resolve all exegetical arguments.

The way a Christian can know that there are two comings of Elijah is by the passage attributed in Isaiah about preparing the way of the Lord. In that passage the Lord tells Elijah to "Comfort my people," because Jerusalem had already received "double" for her sins. John did not preach comfort, but that the axe was already laid at the root of the tree. Only after John was beheaded was Jerusalem destroyed a second time (i.e., twice) by the 10th Legion of Titus c. 68-70 A.D. Therefore, the end-time Elijah will be one who turns hearts to Messiah and comforts them with reassurance of salvation as the nations threaten to destroy the Jewish nation for possession of Jerusalem- or, more specifically, a Muslim capital of Jerusalem. So Elijah will be born again, if you are able to receive the truth of what this means. He and Moses will witness in Jerusalem during a troubling time and be killed and left in the streets. Then the Messiah will come and save the nation from the armies united against it. The city will not be completely destroyed for a third time. (N.B. The first time was by Nebuchadnezzar of the Babylonian Empire c. 586 B.C.)

Understanding these things, we can expect a great awakening among Jews and a restoration of all truths of creation. If Elijah is not heard when he appears, the warning is not a "curse" of the land; it is properly interpreted "lest I strike the earth with utter destruction."

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: True I should have added (cf. Isa. 40:1-3) etc., but in assessing the answers I did not think readers would need to be directed to the passage or other passages.

Comment: True I should have added (cf. Isa. 40:1-3) etc., but in assessing the answers I did not think readers would need to be directed to the passage or other passages.

Answer (score 2):

Some theologians believe that **Enoch and Elijah** will come back again as the **Two Witnesses** of [Revelation 11:1-12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2011:1-12&version=NIV). According to [Hebrews 9:27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%209:27&version=NIV) all men must die once, or at least once. Since Enoch and Elijah are the only two people who have not face death yet, excluding those people at the Rapture [(1 Corinthians 15:51-53)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015:51-53&version=NIV), some theologians believe that they are reserved to die at the end times [(source)](http://www.godsoutreachministryint.org/RevivalEndTimeHARVEST2Witnesses.htm).

**If this is true, then Elijah must return before the final judgement**. Apparently, Elijah and Enoch are now in Heaven or somewhere else, waiting for their time to return to earth at the time of the Antichrist, to be a witness of Christ to the Jews and all nations, to be killed in Jerusalem by the Antichrist, and to be raised again by God after 3 days.

Answer (score 2):

John the Baptist was Elijah. But "spiritually." This was confirmed by Jesus Christ in Matthew 17 and by the angel in Luke 1.

Matthew 17:9-13 (NIV)- "As they were coming down the mountain, Jesus instructed them, “Don’t tell anyone what you have seen, until the Son of Man has been raised from the dead.” The disciples asked him, “Why then do the teachers of the law say that Elijah must come first?” Jesus replied, “To be sure, Elijah comes and will restore all things. **But I tell you, Elijah has already come, and they did not recognize him, but have done to him everything they wished. In the same way the Son of Man is going to suffer at their hands.” Then the disciples understood that he was talking to them about John the Baptist**.

Luke 1:11-17(NIV)- "Then an angel of the Lord appeared to him, standing at the right side of the altar of incense. When Zechariah saw him, he was startled and was gripped with fear. But the angel said to him: “Do not be afraid, Zechariah; your prayer has been heard. Your wife Elizabeth will bear you a son, and you are to call him John. He will be a joy and delight to you, and many will rejoice because of his birth, for he will be great in the sight of the Lord. He is never to take wine or other fermented drink, and he will be filled with the Holy Spirit even before he is born. He will bring back many of the people of Israel to the Lord their God. **And he will go on before the Lord, in the spirit and power of Elijah**, to turn the hearts of the parents to their children and the disobedient to the wisdom of the righteous—to make ready a people prepared for the Lord.”

All prophecies concerning Elijah was fulfilled through John the Baptist.

Comment: Malachi 4:5,6 mentions the "great and awesome day of the LORD" or "great and terrible day of the LORD" which is a direct reference to the Second Coming. See Joel 2:31, Zephaniah 1:10-18 (esp. 18) It is because of this and Malachi 4:5,6 that it is not possible that "All prophecies concerning Elijah was(sic) fulfilled through John the Baptist".

Comment: Second Coming of Jesus was supposed to be in the generation of Jesus' disciples (Matthew 24, Mark 13, Luke 21). Check this link under "Preterism" - http://en.metapedia.org/wiki/Second_coming_of_jesus

Comment: A series of prophecies had to be fulfilled first. Even Enoch was preaching about the Second Coming, but this does not mean that it would come during his time. 2 Thess. 2:1-3 was not fulfilled before 70 A.D. When the 2 Coming of Jesus happens according to 1 Thess. 4, all of the dead righteous are raised from the dead, this has not happened yet. Read 1 Corinthians 15:42-58. Has this happened yet? Especially this part, "We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed ...at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised imperishable, and we shall be changed.

Comment: We still die and still sin, therefore Jesus has NOT come back yet. The last trumpet has not yet sounded. You also have to ignore the whole book of Revelation to believe in Preterism.

Comment: Everything was fulfilled by 70 AD with the coming of Jesus in 70 AD. Jesus came to give us eternal life. Those who believed him  receives eternal life after death. Jesus conquered the REIGN of sin (Romans 5:17, Romans 5:21) over us, not the EXISTENCE of sin. The Last Enemy (spiritual death, condemnation, or separation from God’s fellowship), which is the result of Sin’s reign over us, has been conquered.  As long as humanity exists, the sin will exist.  But Jesus Christ permanently established his “spiritual” kingdom on earth in AD 70 (Luke 9:27,  Luke 17:20-23, etc.).

Comment: Have you ever read the Revelation of Jesus Christ that was given to His servant John? It is clear here that there will be a purging of sin from the entire universe. Humans were not the initiators of sin, Satan was. In the end he will be destroyed, along with all his angels, and Death and Hades will also be destroyed. Without the great tempter, and the consequence of sin with is death, THERE WILL BE NO MORE SIN. Humanity EXISTED without sin and it was because of Satan that sin entered the world. However it will not always be like that.

Comment: In the words of John the Baptist, who we are talking about, Jesus is the "Lamb of God that taketh away the sin of the world." Read 1 John 3:8-10 especially v. 8 which reads, "He that committeth sin is of the devil; for the devil sinneth from the beginning. For this purpose the Son of God was manifested, that he might destroy the works of the devil." God WILL destroy the works of the devil, which is what we call SIN.

Comment: That's because you come from Western Tradition that uses the corrupt Greek version of Revelation and New Testament books. New Testament is written in Aramaic. Not in Greek. Greek NT manuscripts have been tampered to the point where facts are totally unrecognizable. The whole New Testament have been tampered by Greek scribes for to establish their Greek idealogy. You can see tampering and textual variations of Greek NT in the below link - http://en.metapedia.org/wiki/New_Testament

Comment: Friend, your argument falls apart here. When something doesn't fit into your beliefs you just do away with the Bible? Even in the Peshitta Aramaic NT, 1 John 3:8 says exactly the same thing. You want to talk about Greek ideology and false doctrine? Try the immortality of the soul. It is nowhere in the Bible yet you still believe in it. THIS is Greek ideology which CANNOT be supported by the Bible. I challenge you. Find one text which talks about the immortality of the soul. Just one that specifies that the soul is immortal. I can definitely find one that says it is not.

Comment: By the way, I do agree with you that there were dishonest scribes that changed some things to fit their theological view, however these are not ALL Greek Codices, but rather a subset of them which have been tampered with (Codex Sinaiticus and Vaticanus). But what about the Textus Receptus? The Greek Manuscripts that is responsible for pretty much all translations before the 1900s. The text that was copied in secret by the Waldenses who paid for it with their lives. Do you really think that these people who gave up their lives in the Alps change a Book which they thought was worth dying for?

Comment: Greek Manuscripts are responsible for all of the translations only in the corrupt Western Tradition. But not in the East. Several churches in East uses Aramaic NT. All of Greek NT manuscripts are corrupt. For Example, whenever Arameans are mentioned, Greek eliminated Arameans and added Greeks instead. That is total contradiction of first century as Josephus mentioned. Only your claims are falling apart, because you believe in lies. The soul is immortal as it is taught in Matthew 25:31-46. All good souls will have eternal life while all of wicked souls will have eternal punishment.

Comment: Josephus is not inspired. He is simply a historian. Only because he had a hard time learning Greek doesn't mean the inspired writers did. Biblical account is contrary to what you're saying. The disciples did not know a language and by the gift of tongues given by the Holy Spirit they immediately knew the languages, Greek included. Ezekiel 18:20 clearly states, "The soul that sinneth, it shall die..." spoken directly from the mouth of the Almighty. Or are you going to say these are lies also?

Comment: Also about Matthew 25, this clearly says "When the Son of Man comes in his glory, and all the angels with him, then he will sit on the throne of his glory." This definitely has not happened yet, so how could you say that some people are in heaven and some in hell right now? When Jesus came in His first advent, did He come in all His glory? No, but before He was raised in the heavens He said to His disciples that he'd be back for them and he'd come back the same way he left. The Bible also says that on that day every eye shall see Him. In the very text you elected, preterism falls.

Comment: The facts will always be facts even if idiots like you deny it. Afterall, your ancestors do have the tradition of distorting history. Second coming of Jesus was in 70 AD and everyone at Jerusalem saw him in 70 AD. After your death, You will have eternal punishment while I will be in heaven with all of the people who stood for the truth.

Comment: The funny thing is how you take scriptures directly from English as if the scriptures were originally written in English. New Testament is written in Aramaic. Aramaic word for tongue ("Leshna") has multiple meanings. Leshna can mean tongue or accent or dialect or language. The word "life" can also mean "Salvation" while "death" can also mean "eternal punishment" in Aramaic and in Old Hebrew which was spoken before Babylonian captivity.

Comment: I see. No real points. Just insults. Do you really think that this is how Christ treated people? True Christianity is meant to be lived, and it's something you lack. On another note, you did not even try to refute my points. Even when I used the Aramaic NT. And no, the word for death in Ezekiel 18:20 is 'ṯā-mūṯ' which does NOT mean eternal punishment it just means death or dead. I see this will not be constructive for you or me, therefore this is where I stop. I'm saddened by the way you stop your ears without even contemplating on the points I've brought. Take care.

Comment: I did make real points. But since you are the offspring of vipers, you wouldn't believe the truth. You follow the traditions of your corrupt western traditions and nullify the word of God. I am treating you just like Jesus Christ treated Blasphemous pharisees and scribes in first century (Matthew 23, Luke 11). You follow the corrupt OT and NT texts written in Hebrew and Greek for your own theories just like your ancestors did. I doubt you will escape the condemnation of hell.

Comment: You use Hebrew Masoretic Text which was written around 8th century AD which is filled with corruption and contradictions. The language of Jesus in first century AD was Aramaic. Not Hebrew or Greek. Of Course, you wouldn't understand the truth due to the fact that you are like a corrupt pharisee.

Comment: "Wherefore by their fruits ye shall know them." All you are doing is displaying the character of the enemy, friend. Jesus never called them idiots. And even when He spoke to them harshly it was out of love. It is evident that you don't. By the way, have you heard of the Dead Sea Scrolls? Apparently not.

Comment: You are the one who is displaying the character of the enemy through lies and deception. Jesus called Jews "Serpents" and also their father is devil (John 8:44). Everyone is learning about Dead Sea Scrolls Propaganda. Jews use Dead Sea Scrolls to claim that Hebrew was spoken more than 2000 years. But Dead Sea Scrolls Archaeologist Yadin points out that it was Pseudo Messiah Bar Kokhba who revived Hebrew for the purpose of his messianic idealogy. Jesus taught to follow the OT laws and opposed Traditions of the Elders which later came to be known as Talmud.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, you must understand what Elijah's mission was, what he did and also what John the Baptist did as Jesus said:

> “Assuredly, I say to you, among those born of women there has not
> risen one greater than John the Baptist; but he who is least in the
> kingdom of heaven is greater than he. And from the days of John the
> Baptist until now the kingdom of heaven suffers violence, and the
> violent take it by force. For all the prophets and the law prophesied
> until John. And if you are willing to receive it, **he is Elijah who
> is to come**. He who has ears to hear, let him hear!"
>
> Matthew 11:11-14

John the Baptist was not the same Elijah, but He carried out Elijah's mission and purpose. In the same way, there will be an Elijah in the last days.

> Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of the
> great and dreadful day of the Lord: and he shall turn the heart of the
> fathers to the children, and the heart of the children to their
> fathers, lest I come and smite the earth with a curse. Malachi 4:5, 6.
>
> The closing words of Malachi are a prophecy regarding the work that
> should be done preparatory to the first and the second advent of
> Christ. Those who are to prepare the way for the second coming of
> Christ are represented by faithful Elijah, as John came in the spirit
> of Elijah to prepare the way for Christ’s first advent. Our message
> must be as direct as was that of John. He rebuked kings for their
> iniquity. Notwithstanding the peril his life was in, he never allowed
> truth to languish on his lips.... In this time of well-nigh universal
> apostasy, God calls upon His messengers to proclaim His law in the
> spirit and power of Elias. As John the Baptist, in preparing a people
> for Christ’s first advent, called their attention to the Ten
> Commandments, so we are to give, with no uncertain sound, the message:
> “Fear God, and give glory to him; for the hour of his judgment is
> come.” With the earnestness that characterized Elijah the prophet and
> John the Baptist, we are to strive to prepare the way for Christ’s
> second advent. The hour of God’s judgment has come, and upon the
> members of His church on earth rests the solemn responsibility of
> giving warning to those who are standing as it were on the very brink
> of eternal ruin. All can do something in the work. None will be
> pronounced guiltless before God unless they have worked earnestly and
> unselfishly for the salvation of souls. Your duty cannot be shifted
> upon another. No one but yourself can do your work. If you withhold
> your light, someone must be left in darkness through your neglect. The
> Lord has a place for everyone in His great plan.
>
> The Faith I live By, P. 290

Answer (score 0):

Jhaverde is correct.

Paul saying All of these die doesn't include Enoch since Paul said several verses prior that Enoch did not experience death. Plus, there are several references to Enoch pseudepigraphal texts that refer to Enoch being taken or removed from the earth. Noah knee his grandfather was taken from the earth.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.